# Claiming use of home as office allowance if the work is unpaid

Tags: legal, expenses, uk, hmrc

Can I claim the use of home as office allowance if the work that I perform there is (currently) unpaid? I am currently working on a web project that I'm developing in my office at home. I'm spending a significant portion of my week working on the project, but it's out of hours (usually 4-6 hours per evening and some time on the weekend). So it's a high sum total of weekly hours, but it isn't my day job (I'm working in a contract for a client during the day) so I'm wondering whether I would be able to claim the allowance or whether it's simply a red flag that it isn't worth waving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to receive wages to claim home office as a business expense, however, you do need to use the office exclusively for that business and not for personal purposes.

**For the US,** see [this summary from TurboTax](http://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Small-Business-Taxes/The-Home-Office-Deduction/INF12067.html) for more detailed information.

**For the UK,** as long as the office space has no other use **for the time you are working** you can deduct the expenses for that specific time frame. See [this explanation from HMRC](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/bimmanual/BIM47810.htm).